# How can I make a "board of tiles" for this game?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to make a board consisting of tiles but I do not know how to fill up the entire board area. I have only gotten up to 1 column of the board, as shown in the image. How can I fill this board so that each tile can be changed if clicked on or such?

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center; 
}

hr {
    width: 500px;
}

#board {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    float: center;
    display: grid;
    background-color: rgb(126, 124, 122);
    border: 6px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.tile {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid bisque;
    border-radius: 10%;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.picker {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid bisque;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10%;
    align-content: left;
    align-self: left;
}

.tile {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
}

.float-child {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    vertical-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Play-Color</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="float-child">
      <button class="picker" style="background-color: red"></button>
      <h4>count = 0</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="picker" style="background-color: blue"></button>
      <h4>count = 0</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="picker" style="background-color: green"></button>
      <h4>count = 0</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="picker" style="background-color: yellow"></button>
      <h4>count = 0</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="picker" style="background-color: grey"></button>
      <h4>count = 0</h4>
      <br>
      <button class="picker"></button>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="board" class="float-child" style="position:relative; left:900px; top:-1000px" >
      <button class="tile"></button>
      <button class="tile"></button>
      <button class="tile"></button>
      <button class="tile"></button>
      <button class="tile"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[2][UpdatedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnUso.png)

........................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Fill it? .... how do you mean? Aren't you missing some more elements than?

Comment: why not code a `grid` either harc-coded through HTML or generated through JS. In any case I would not use a `button` but a simple `div` and use an `eventListerner` to check for `click`-events.

Comment: Why your game is not responsive? Your elements are all out of place. It's unclear what that game does, what cells do you want, need, etc etc. Could you please describe exactly what you want?

Comment: you dont need buttons to be clickable. Also way to much coding if a simple click event would check for which element is clicked on and literally just takes `element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //commands
});`

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps to achieve the wanted result. Normally I wouldn't code this on SO. I just did it because I had fun it it. For the feature dont expect others to code a whole game for you for free!

See the comments within HTML, CSS and JS for furtehr info.

1. You have to create your color to pick from. The smartest solution IMHO is the use of radio-buttons. The Radio button will even without a script only allow the selection of one choice:
   `<input type="radio" name="color" value="color-name" id="color-name">`
2. To not break the game you should always have one color selected. To ensure that on start one color is already selected you add the `checked`-attribtue to one color such as:
   `<input type="radio" ... checked>`
3. Next you have to hide the checkboxes to be invisible and not cunsumign any space which you do through CSS:
   `input { display: none; }`
4. Then you have to add the color as visual box by adding a `<label>`. That has the advantage that you can click on the label and it will select the correct radio button:
   `<label for="`color-name">
5. After that you color the label with the color you want. While you do that, you can also set a CSS-Class to the same color in the same instance to allow the painting with that color:

```css
label[for=color-name],
.color-name {
  background-color: color-name;
}
```

6. Finally you have to create a grid. You can do that easily through JS or hardcode it to HTML. Sicne I dont want to explain you on how to do it correctly through JS (which would cost me another 30 minutes of my lifetime) I will hardcode it through HTML. In my case I used a grid-container: `<div class="game-board">`. Then I added 25x child elements: `<div class="card"></div>`. To make the grid `5x5` dimensions I used CSS on the Grid-Container to create 5 columns:

```css
.game-board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

7. As said already in the comments, you don't need buttons to be clickable for JS. The label of the radio buttons are clickable already (as they are labels). You can run a script even when not being clickable by simply usign the `EventListener` to check for a `click`-event by using JS:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // statements
});
```

8. To only select the `grid-cards` and not the `container` itself or possibel other content you can check if the element that was clicked on contains a specific class:

```js
if (e.target.classList.contains('card')) {
  // statements
}
```

9. In case that `grid-card` already has a color as CSS-Class applied to, we have to remove all potencial classes that would prevent the CSS to work correctly (it would only show the color of the class that is listed last in CSS):
   `e.target.className = ''`
10. Unfortunatly the last step also removed the `card` class and as such we have to re-add this class:
    `e.target.classList.add('card');`
11. Once we did that, we use a `switch-case`-statement which is cleaner then writing tons of `if/else`-statements. You can google guides and tutorials on your own. That `switch`-statement now checks what radio-button is checked and applies a class to the element you clicked on that adds the background-color:
    `e.target.classList.add('color-name');`

**EDIT**

1. To include a counter you can use the JS `lenght`-statement:
   `document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .color-name').length`. this statement will count the number of elements that contain a specific class.
2. Then simply use `innerHTML`-statement to display the count:
   `element.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .color-name').length`

```js
var board = document.querySelector('.game-board')

// eventListener to listen to click events on the game board
board.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.clear();
  // checks if a card and not the agme baord itself was clicked on
  if (e.target.classList.contains('card')) {
    const card = e.target.classList;
    // checks which color has been selected
    var color = document.querySelector('.color-picker input:checked').value;
    
    // removes all classes from the clicked on element to allow re-painting
    e.target.className = '';
    // re-adds the "card" class to the clicked element
    card.add('card');
    
    // switch statement to add the class with the selected color to paint the grid-card
    switch (color) {
      case "red":
        card.add('red');
        break;
      case "blue":
        card.add('blue');
        break;
      case "green":
        card.add('green');
        break;
      case "yellow":
        card.add('yellow');
        break;
      case "gray":
        card.add('gray');
        break;
    }
    
    // color-counter
    var countRed = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .red').length,
        countBlue = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .blue').length,
        countGreen = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .green').length,
        countYellow = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .yellow').length,
        countGray = document.querySelectorAll('.game-board .gray').length;
        
    // displaying the counter
    var labelRed = document.querySelector('#count-red span'),
        labelBlue = document.querySelector('#count-blue span'),
        labelGreen = document.querySelector('#count-green span'),
        labelYellow = document.querySelector('#count-yellow span'),
        labelGray = document.querySelector('#count-gray span');
    labelRed.innerHTML = countRed;
    labelBlue.innerHTML = countBlue;
    labelGreen.innerHTML = countGreen;
    labelYellow.innerHTML = countYellow;
    labelGray.innerHTML = countGray;    
  }
});
```

```css
/* aligning the color picker and game board next to each other */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* box for the color */
.color-picker {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  gap: 10px;
}

/* hides the radio button */
.color-picker > input {
  display: none;
}

/* creatign a visual border to see what color has been selected */
input:checked + label {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

/* setting a "color-box" to the radio-button */
.color-picker > label {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  min-width: 50px;
}

/* settign the color of the color picker and classes for painting */
label[for=red],
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

label[for=blue],
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

label[for=green],
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

label[for=yellow],
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

label[for=gray],
.gray {
  background-color: gray;
}

/* game board that creates a board of 5x5 with equal dimensions */
.game-board {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

/* Setting the grid-cards to be squares */
.game-board > .card {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* To make the grid-cards and label appear like buttons on hover */
.color-picker > label:hover,
.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Letting you select the color -->
<div class="color-picker">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" id="red" checked>
  <label for="red"></label>
  <div id="count-red">Count: <span>0</span></div>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue">
  <label for="blue"></label>
  <div id="count-blue">Count: <span>0</span></div>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green">
  <label for="green"></label>
  <div id="count-green">Count: <span>0</span></div>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow">
  <label for="yellow"></label>
  <div id="count-yellow">Count: <span>0</span></div>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="gray" id="gray">
  <label for="gray"></label>
  <div id="count-gray">Count: <span>0</span></div>
</div>

<!-- The game board as a grid -->
<div class="game-board">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The border is not added by default. Its because of followign CSS-declaration: `input:checked + label { border: 3px solid black; }`

Comment: you have to loop through every element and use a coutner as variable that you then display. I can apply that in about 1h.